# I want to integrate reviewsmaker.com iframe to website main page for displaying reviews, but its getting redirect to their website during page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-apps-script

integrating "reviewsmaker.com" iframe to website main page for displaying reviews, but getting redirect to "reviewsmaker.com" website during page load. why?

"reviewsmaker.com" iframe redirecting my website home-page to their website.. that iframe was showing reviews properly. but suddenly it causing redirect issue.

My Code Snippet:

```
<iframe src="https://gmb.reviewsmaker.com/widget/widget.php?pid=XXXXXXX" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="reviewsmaker" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="550px"></iframe>
```

please suggest me changes to solve it.

Comment: You're saying it used to be working properly, correct?

Comment: Sandbox it````````?````````

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the issue; the issue has been resolved. We had people attempting to abuse the service and with the blacklist blocks it appeared some sites were going through a loop and not passing our check;

The issue should've been resolved and you can integrate your Google / Facebook reviews back to your sites.

Give it a shot:

```
<iframe src="https://gmb.reviewsmaker.com/widget/widget.php?pid=ChIJF0VmctNewokR_K9I5WWqVDo" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="reviewsmaker" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="550px"></iframe>
```

Note if you are not loading the Page ID correctly after several attempts you may get flagged; you can always post here or reach services@reviewsmaker.com in the future. Remember to use the full Place ID; you can decode it easily on https://reviewsmaker.com or Google's own Place Decoder: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder

If you'd like to use the Facebook Reviews Widget you can simply frame the URL: http://gmb.reviewsmaker.com/widget/facebook.php?pid=1107834585994793 where pid= is your Facebook Page ID; if you need to locate your Facebook Page ID you can do so easily at https://findmyfbid.com/.

Thank you once more for reporting the issue,

— Developer @ reviewsmaker.com